# WebView Url not full load in iOS10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest, ios10

Same url in run in lower then iOS10 (ex. iOS8,iOS9) work properly.

```
-(void) loadUrl

 {
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://myurl.com";

   //Create a URL object.
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

  //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 //Load the request in the UIWebView.
  [detailWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine in ios 10 and xCode 8.

I used this,

```
-(void) loadUrl

{
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

And call this method where you want using `[self loadUrl];`

Add URLSchemes in your plist file for your url.

I am getting webview like,

[image: ios 10 WebView]

Your code is not wrong.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: WebView url not fully load it just partially load in iOS10. for asking Question i used dummy url.

Comment: can you post the image that what you are getting? @Nikunj

Answer (score 0):

In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView.import webkit.h and use this code

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: Did this apple url also not loaded properly.